# Homebrew ENV CMAKE set to OpenGL Framework by default. How to change?

Tags: cmake, environment-variables, homebrew

I have on my Mac homebrew installed. The brew --env output as follows:

```
HOMEBREW_CC: clang
HOMEBREW_CXX: clang++
MAKEFLAGS: -j8
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /usr/local
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR: /usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/11
HOMEBREW_GIT: git
HOMEBREW_SDKROOT: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk
PATH: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

as you can see the CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH pointing to *.../OpenGL.framework*

this ruing any installation with homebrew since the *OpenGL.framework* don't have *math.h* for instance.

is any way to change the hombrew **CMAKE_** environment?

I have tried so far reinstall XCode and XCode Command Line. Deleted and installed back homebrew, including all Cellars ...

Thanks!

[UPDATE]

while searching for the solution, discovered the function in the file super.rb under */usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/ENV*  name **determine_cmake_include_path** which is setting these *CMAKE env* for itself:

```
sig { returns(T.nilable(PATH)) }
def determine_cmake_include_path
 PATH.new(homebrew_extra_cmake_include_paths).existing
end
```

since this is not a subject of my "deep knowledge" :) would appreciate if somebody can give a light on what is going on there ... while I'm still searching for solution ....